# How to serialize complex multiple level model inside model objects and send via GET web api?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

As the title said, I appreciate it if anyone recommend any resources or libraries.

Updated objects that I would like to serialize in querystring below or kindly advice:

```
public class DTOClassroom
{
    public string SpreadsheetTitle { get; set; }
    public List<DTOClassroomMonthlyTest> MonthlyTests { get; set; }
    public List<DTOClassroomSpecialty_Subject> Specialty_Subjects { get; set; }
}

public class DTOClassroomMonthlyTest
{
    public int Term_MonthId { get; set; }
    public int MonthId { get; set; }
    public string MonthCalculationType { get; set; }
}

public class DTOClassroomSpecialty_Subject
{
    public int Specialty_SubjectId { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<DTOClassroomSpecialty_SubjectChild> ChildColumns { get; set; }
}

public class DTOClassroomSpecialty_SubjectChild
{
    public int ActivityId { get; set; }
    public int Sort { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Scope { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Please show an example and what you have tried so far.

Comment: Hi @Kamnab Kuoch, Why do you want any resources or libraries? Default serializer can bind the complex model to query string in web api.

Comment: I have updated the DTO object class in the question.

Comment: Hi @KamnabKuoch, If you want to pass complex model to query string, just send request like: `https://localhost:portNumber/xxx?MonthlyTests[0].MonthId=1&MonthlyTests[1].MonthId=2&Specialty_Subjects [0].IsSelected =true&Specialty_Subjects [0].ChildColumns[0].Name=aa`.

Comment: Thank @Rena! Is there any way just pass only for example: DTOClassroom and generate the inner and sub-inner properties to querystring?